# How to ensure Generic's Type is a Closure

Tags: swift, generics, closures

I am trying to make a generic class in swift that ensures its type argument is a closure. This closure can take any number of arguments of any type.

```
class ClassWithClosure<Closure> {}

var sensical = ClassWithClosure<(Int) -> Double>() // This is okay.
var alsoFine = ClassWithClosure<(String, String) -> Bool>() // This is also okay.
var nonsensical = ClassWithClosure<String>() // This shouldn't work.
```

The trouble I am having is that generic type constraints can only be classes or protocols.

> ([Swift Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID186))
>   Type constraints specify that a type parameter must inherit from a specific class, or conform to a particular protocol or protocol composition.

As far as I can see, there are no classes from which only closures inherit and no protocols to which only closures conform.

The two options I can see are:

- Have no type constraints on my class, and just discourage misuse through comments.
  The trouble with this is that what type something is seems like something that should be enforced, not merely suggested.
- Not use a generic class, and just use the type `(_: Any...) -> Any?` wherever the closure is used.
  Again, this gets rid of swifts nice type checking.

Both of these options seem questionable and I suspect there is a better way. Is there some way to restrict the type argument of this generic class to a closure?

Comment: I can't think of a situation where you would need this. I think this is likely an XY problem. What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: @Sweeper I am trying to group together a number of classes that all hold some data and have an array of closures which they call whenever their data undergoes some specific change. They had quite a bit of code in common that I already successfully put in a superclass, this would allow me to make things just a little bit tidier.  

Although my question may not address the best approach, I was hoping to learn something about closures and perhaps be able to apply it to other situations. If this is not a good way to ask questions, please let me know and I will change it, as I am still new.

Comment: In fact, a more sophisticated support from the language would be helpful, IMHO. For example, it would be nice to let us define constraints on a closure's signature: `func foo<F: Closure>(f: F) where F.Return == Int, F.Arg0 == Bool`